# Código ou script "Carregando..."

Tags: script

Gostaria de saber qual o código ou script para aparecer aquela famosa frase (**Carregando...**).

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: ao menos especifique qual o ambiente ou a linguagem

Answer (score 1):

pode ser feito com ajax ao carregar requisições

```
$('document').ready(function(){

        $("#btn-login").click(function(){
            var data = $("#login-form").serialize();

            $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url  : '../php/seila.php',
                data : data,
                dataType: 'json',
                beforeSend: function()
                {   
                    $("#btn-login").html('Carregando...'); <---
                },
                success :  function(response){                      


                }
            });
        });

    });
```